# Need formula to Vlookup comma separated values in a single cell for find Max Date

Tags: microsoft-excel

i am working on Gantt Chart and i need a formula for check max date by predecessors dependent task

[image: Gantt Chart Small Format]

i need to check dates from predecessor and wbs link and find max or min date.

as i am not able to check multiple predecessor reference separate by comma and i getting error

how can i check multiple predecessor end date by reference and find max date to start task after previous complete.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and manually type in the expected result. Then explain the logic that leads to that result.

Comment: Hi @Umashankar Doyal,, are U looking to get  earliest/latest dates based on order of predecessors like top 10 as latest date!! Also [edit] your post & share the formula you have use & expected result.

Answer (score 1):

With due credit to "FlexYourData" above:
Slightly enhanced when integers and decimals are involved.

`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK([@Prdcsr])),IFNA(MAX(XLOOKUP(SplitCSV([@Prdcsr]),[Seq],[Tg Dt])),MAX(XLOOKUP(INT(SplitCSV([@Prdcsr])),[Seq],[Tg Dt]))),"")`

**@Prdcsr** = Predecessor task column cell (lookup value)

**[Seq]** = Tasks sequence column

**[Tg Dt]** = Target Date column

If decimals are involved (as sub-tasks), and then int() portion will not work. Hence using this.

Answer (score 0):

Use AGGREGATE with ISNUMBER(SEARCH())

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,7,$F$2:$F$18/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&$A$2:$A$18&",",","&C3&",")),1),"")
```

[image]

---

Or this array formula that creates an array of numbers and uses INDEX/MATCH to return an array of dates to the MAX.

```
=IFERROR(MAX(INDEX(F:F,MATCH(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(C3,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),A:A,0))),"")
```

The differences are that the first will iterate whole column of data twice for each time it is used.  The second only iterates the numbers in the target cell, But depending on ones version it may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter each time to exit edit mode to make work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

previously i write a formula but here is an error that it's not work after dependencies number 9 its' not working

=IF($F15="Finish-to-Start (FS)",MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$13:$B$382,$G15)),$K$13:$K$382,999))+1,TODAY())

Answer (score 0):

=IFNA(IFS($F135="Finish-to-Start (FS)", XLOOKUP($G135,$B$13:$B419,$K$13:$K419)+$H135,$F135="Start-to-Start (SS)", XLOOKUP($G135,$B$13:$B419,$J$13:$J419)+$H135,$F135="Finish-to-Finish (FF)",  XLOOKUP($G135,$B$13:$B419,$K$13:$K419)-($L135+$H135),$F135="Start-to-Finish (SF)", XLOOKUP($G135,$B$13:$B419,$K$13:$K419)+$H135),TODAY())

After A lot Try came back to Basic Formula which help me good but on for Single Dependencies if i add another reference by comma then it's not work and that task i have to do manual part

Answer (score 0):

You can create a very simple VBA function to split the comma-separated values into an array, then use worksheet functions to get what you need.

I created a function called SplitCSV, which looks like this:

```
Public Function SplitCSV(ByRef csv As String) As String()

SplitCSV = Split(csv, ",")

End Function
```

You can just add a module to your VBA editor and paste that right in there.

My data looks like this:
[image]

The function to get the max end date of all the items in the list of predecessors is this (example formula from row 9 in the image above):

```
=MAX(XLOOKUP(INT(SplitCSV(B9)),$A$2:$A$18,$D$2:$D$18))
```

To break it down, SplitCSV takes the comma-separated predecessors and returns an array of each item, after using the VBA Split() function.

We wrap that returned array, which is an array of Strings, in the INT function to convert each item to an integer (whole number).

That array of integers is then passed as the lookup value to XLOOKUP, which searches for each item in column A and returns the End date from column D.

In this way, XLOOKUP will return an array of dates - the end dates for each of the predecessors.

Wrapping the whole thing with MAX makes sure we get a single date - the maximum date from the array of dates.